# How to get value of Select option from loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I want to get / fetch value of select option from for-each loop in JavaScript

code

```
 <?php $user = $this->admin_model->getData('user'); ?>

 <select class="form-control" name="user" id="user">
        <option value="">Select User to Assign</option>
           <?php foreach ($user as $row): ?>
               <option value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><?php echo $row->user_name</option>
           <?php endforeach; ?>
 </select>
```

Comment: By my knowledge foreach makes an array, not an object. So access like $row[‘id’] instead

Comment: It through Error " Cannot use object of type stdClass as array "

Comment: why do you need to get that through java script? @user9972185

Comment: It might help to post your getData function

Comment: Actually wanted to post data to ajax and i want that selected user id to post...

Comment: What is your real question? There is no JS code given in your question....

Comment: That's what i need JS code, i don't know how to do it in JS @NicoHaase

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
<?php $user = $this->admin_model->getData('user'); ?>

 <select class="form-control" name="user" id="user" onchange="getValue(this)">
    <option value="">Select User to Assign</option>
       <?php foreach ($user as $row): ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><?php echo $row->user_name;?></option>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>

<script>
function getValue(sel){
   var optionvalue = sel.value;

    alert(optionvalue);

}
</script>
```

Comment: It gives Uncaught ReferenceError

Comment: In options  ;?>  is missing

Comment: check your options value $row->id; is exist or not?

Comment: Ok try now i updated the code both code is working for me try this one.

Comment: Hey thanks man it works but i want to post it in ajax and my ajax is in different function, how to do that

Comment: you want to pass this data on onChange event?

Comment: then just call your function into this function

Comment: Just replace your function with alert

Comment: Hey, thanks man it works but it only post onchange value data and it post null (undefine) value to other function variable data in ajax...

Comment: hey, i want to ask something, that how to alert selected option TEXT in your method, i have tried every thing but didn't find any solution....

Comment: <script>
function getValue(sel){
   var optionvalue = sel.value;
   var selectedValue = sel.find("option:selected");

    alert(selectedValue);

}
</script>

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myAlert(el){
  alert(el.options[el.selectedIndex].value);
}
```

```html
 <select onchange="myAlert(this)" class="form-control" name="user" id="user">
            <option value="">Select User to Assign</option>
            <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
            <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
     </select>
```

Comment: Hey thanks... but my values are coming from database

Comment: But that's no difference. Your data comes from database and is rendered to page. Your DOM should be looking like that after rendering, or? Do you have a problem to put your database values in your selectbox or to get the selected value via JS after user changes?

Comment: Hey i want to store that data in JS variable and post it through AJAX but couldn't find how to fetch data from select option and store in JS variable...

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Hey thanks man it...works, i want to ask how to access this data to other function

Comment: Get selected value from everywhere:
`document.getElementById("user").options(document.getElementById("user").selectedIndex).value`